# Possible to determine amount of creatine from package details?

Tags: creatine

After the loading phase, one should be able to take a steady-state amount of [3-5 grams of creatine a day](https://www.bodybuilding.com/content/how-to-take-creatine-clearing-up-the-confusion.html).  The information available on supplements' packaging can be confusing (image below).  When the labelling seems to refer to the mass of a capsule, are there any common conventions that are assumed for inferring the amount of creatine?

[image]

Comment: Note that this patented "buffered" creatine is no better than regular creatine monohydrate. It's just a whole lot more expensive for no benefit. https://doi.org/10.1186/1550-2783-9-43

Comment: Huh!  I was just following the advice of someone who researches this online.  Can you suggest alternatives?

Comment: Just buy pure creatine monohydrate. It's cheap, simple, and proven. Anything claiming to be a better form of creatine is almost certainly a scam.

Comment: Okay.  Thanks for that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a standard way to [read supplement labels](https://www.crnusa.org/resources/how-read-supplement-label). The linked webpage is a useful visualization. There is an "active" section and an "other" or "non-active" section in a supplement. Usually the ingredients of interest are listed in the first section with their amount.

In this case, each serving of 2 capsules contains 1500 mg of the 'patented' creatine-blend. Therefore, each capsule contains 750 mg of creatine-blend. In some scenarios, the additional non-medicinal ingredients would be in excess of the amount listed (i.e. each capsule might actually weigh 800 mg = 750 mg creatine + 50 mg non-medicinal) but they can also be included. In your case, you can actually look at the [patent filed for the creatine-blend](https://patents.google.com/patent/US6399661B1/en) and find that:

> In capsule form, the capsule includes the following formulation:
>
> Creatine Monohydrate, 1000 mg
> Maltodextrin, 200 mg
> Magnesium Stearate, 5 mg
> Magnesium Glycerol Phosphate, 25 mg
> Soda Ash, 5-1000 mg
> Natural and/or Artificial Flavors, 20 mg
>
> The method for making capsules is to place 1000 mg of creatine monohydrate in a mixing vessel. The pH is adjusted to be between 7 and 14 by adding soda ash. The maltodextrin, magnesium stearate (a flow agent) and natural and/or artificial flavors are added to desired taste and sweetness. The pH is again checked, and magnesium glycerol phosphate is added to adjust the pH to be between 7 and 14. The mixed powder is then processed by a conventional encapsulation machine which prepares capsules of the powder.

So, in this case you can see that each capsule serving contains 1 g of creatine monohydrate. IMO, this is uncommon to know the makeup of proprietary blends but this is a great example of how labels can be misleading.

I'd gamble that if you were to read the directions they instruct you to take 4 capsules per day to meet the 3 g maintenance phase requirement. However, we can now see that you'd only be getting 2 g of creatine monohydrate.

Comment: I can see the 1500mg, but how did you infer that it refers to creatine as opposed to all of the materials listed?  It does say 4 capsules, but it would be reassuring to know the logic behind the certainty that 1500mg refers to creatine.

Comment: Maybe it's implied by the thick lines, in contrast to the thin lines.  The headings between a pair of thick lines refer to the line items that follow, up to the next pair of thick lines that straddle headings.  If so, there is a lot of guesswork there.

Comment: @user2153235 it says that each (2 capsule) serving contains 1500mg of their patented creatine (which is a mixture of some amount of magnesium in addition to the creatine), plus unspecified amounts of the "non-medical" ingredients. So the other materials listed do not count towards the 1500mg, but that 1500mg is also not pure creatine monohydrate.

Comment: @user2153235 I edited my answer and looked into it a bit more for you. I was curious myself. Your answer is that usually you don't know, and this is why "proprietary blends" without listed ingredients are not worth your money.

Comment: Wow.  Your research-fu is strong.  Thanks so much!